# How to write to my filesystem from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to save incoming images, I decided to save it in my filesystem, but unfortunately, it is unavailable from a docker container, I am about to save images inside the home directory 
I am using golang and this the path where I am saving

`home, _ := os.UserHomeDir() 
 dir := home + "/Desktop/5"` (root/Desktop/5)

how can I save images inside my filesystem not inside the container 
I have tried to add volume inside my docker-compose file

```
    volumes:
    #path inside container 
  - /root

  # path in my filesystem to map 
  - $HOME/Desktop/root
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mount a directory on your host to the docker container:

```
volumes:
  - "/home/myname/root:/root"
```

With this volume definition in docker-compose, whatever the container writes under /root in the container should show up in your /home/myname/root directory.